# Product topology for $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and generating subbasis

Tags: general-topology, product-space

The product topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is defined to be the topology generated by the subbasis:

$$S_n := \{ \pi_n ^{-1} (U) :  U \subseteq \mathbb{R} \text{ open}\} $$

where $\pi_n$  are the projection maps from the product space to the component space. Now I learned the product topology as the topology with least number of open sets such that the projection maps are continuous (although I never understood the "why" for this definition). However, I don't quite get why the subbasis above would generate the product topology (I actually don't even know how can a subbasis "directly" generate a topology since I always though that a topology is generated by the union of basis elements, so first we would need to construct the basis from the subbasis and then get the topology).

Comment: When you have a subbasis you can get a basis by doing finite intersection of the elements of the subbasis, and then you consider the topology generated by this basis. And then you get that it's topology generated by sets of the type $\prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}}V_n$, where each $V_n$ is an open set and $V_n\neq \mathbb{R}$ for a finite number of $n's$. Also regarding is your comment on the product topology being the smallest topology such that the project maps are continuous this is due to the fact that if you have a topology where these maps are continuous , then $\pi_n^{-1}(U)$ is open

Comment: in that topology and so since it's a topology you will have finite intersections of this and then their unions and this gives exactly the product topology, and so this topology will contain the product topology, making the product topology the smallest topology such that the projection maps are continuous. The why is because sometimes people are interested in the smallest topology for which some map is continuous, in this case we have the projections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The product topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is defined to be the topology generated by the subbasis:
> $$S_n := \{ \pi_n ^{-1} (U) :  U \subseteq \mathbb{R} \text{ open}\} $$

Although you're saying the correct thing, this notation is not correct. You want to take into the subbasis the sets $\pi_n ^{-1}(U)$ *for all $n$'s*. So the right notation would be
$$\mathcal S := \{ \pi_n ^{-1} (U) :  U \subseteq \mathbb{R} \text{ open}, n\in\mathbb N\}.$$
(The main thing I object to in the notation you wrote down is that it looks as if the subbasis depends on $n$.)

> the topology with least number of open sets such that the projection maps are continuous (although I never understood the "why" for this definition)

Well, if you want $\pi_n$ to be continuous, then $\pi_n^{-1}(U)$ has to be open for every open set $U$. This is basically the definition of continuity.

So you want the topology which contains all such sets, i.e., a topology which contains $\mathcal S$. Saying that $\mathcal S$ is a subbasis is simply saying that you are taking the smallest topology which contains $\mathcal S$.

> I actually don't even know how can a subbasis "directly" generate a topology since I always though that a topology is generated by the union of basis elements

If you have a subbasis $\mathcal S$, then the corresponding basis is obtained as set of all finite intersections of elements from $\mathcal S$.
$$\mathcal B=\{S_1\cap \dots \cap S_k; k\in\mathbb N, S_i\in\mathcal S \text{ for }i=1,2,\dots,k\}.$$
Here, if you work with projections, the basis for the product topology on $\prod\limits_{i\in I} X_i$ can be written simply in this way
$$\mathcal B=\{\pi_{i_1}^{-1}(U_1) \cap \pi_{i_2}^{-1}(U_2) \cap \dots \cap \pi_{i_k}^{-1}(U_k); k\in\mathbb N, U_j\text{ is open in }X_{i_j}\text{ for }i=1,2,\dots,k\}.$$

In you case the index set is $\mathbb N$ and each $X_n$ is equal to $\mathbb R$. So you're dealing with sequences of real numbers. A reasonable ways to visualize the basic open sets is that you have chosen finitely many coordinates $i_1,\dots,i_k$ and for each of those coordinates you've chosen some open sets. And you're taking only the sequences where the $i_k$-th term belongs to the chosen open set $U_k$. (On coordinates outside of the set $\{i_1,\dots,i_k\}$, the sequences belonging to this particular basic open set can behave arbitrarily.)

Still, even if you prefer to use basis to generating topologies, it might be useful to work (at least sometimes) with subbasis. For example, here in the case of product topology, you can see that the description using subbasis is much simpler.

Comment: Thanks the justification for the "coarsest topology that makes the projection maps cts". Now those conditions seem enough for me to construct a set that has the least number open sets, but how does one "immediately" recognize that it forms a subbasis?

Comment: @mathripper Saying that "$\mathcal S$ is a subbasis for the topology $\mathcal T$" is basically the same as saying that "$\mathcal T$ is the smallest topology containing $\mathcal S$". (Maybe with some minor caveats, it all depends a bit on the exact definition your text is using. But if you have $X\in\mathcal S$, then there should be no problem with either of the common conventions.)

Comment: I will also add a link to this question: [Intuition about subbasis for a topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1996217). As mentioned in the accepted answer there, the only condition that $\mathcal S$ has to fulfill in order to be a subbase for *some topology* on $X$ is that $\bigcup\mathcal S=X$, i.e., that $\mathcal S$ covers the whole space. But some authors do not even require this conditions.